# Filter values out when plotting with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is is possible to filter out values when plotting with Pandas? I'm plotting like:

```
df.plot(x=dates, y=title, linestyle='-', marker='+', linewidth=0.1)
```

I would like to plot only values lower the `10000` i.e, something like:

```
df.plot(x=dates, y=title, linestyle='-', marker='+', linewidth=0.1, filterLessThen=0.1)
```

The `dates` parameter is a timestamp like i.e. `2004 006 01 00 01 37 600`.

And the full (all columns) data file is:

```
TIME                      XGSM         YGSM         ZGSM         BXGSM        BYGSM        BZGSM         BT   
2004 006 01 00 01 37 600  -2.0299      -6.3763      -6.5707      -21.272      -61.883      -27.834       71.113    
2004 006 01 00 02 32 800  -2.0252      -6.3889      -6.5644      -22.069      -62.802      -27.386       71.985    
2004 006 01 00 03 28 000  -2.0206      -6.4015      -6.5582      -21.615      -63.592      -25.709       71.922  
2004 006 01 10 25 23 200  0.53396       1.2104      0.94721      0.10000E+35  0.10000E+35  0.10000E+35  0.10000E+35
```

I would like to exclude those `0.10000E+35` from the plot.

Full code I'm working on:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df.ix[:,0], format='%Y 0%m %d %H %M %S %f')
for title in titles:
    if(df[title].dtype == np.float64 or df[title].dtype == np.int64):
        print title
        df.plot(x=dates, y=title, linestyle='-', marker='+', linewidth=0.1)
        plt.xlabel("")
        plt.savefig('img/'+title+'.png' ,bbox_inches='tight')
        plt.close()
```

Comment: just filter prior to plotting: `df[df<0.1].plot(x=dates, y=title, linestyle='-', marker='+', linewidth=0.1)`

Comment: What is `dates`? sample values??

Comment: Question edited, adding sample date.

Comment: So what's wrong with your current solution?

Comment: @KcFnMi - need replace `0.10000E+35` to `0` before plot?